# How to access _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> value in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the data returned by placeid of google map.

```
 "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 28.55616239999999,
            "lng" : 77.0999578
         },
         .....
         }



var result = jsonDecode(response.body)['result']['geometry']['location'];
print(result); //{lat: 28.6862738, lng: 77.2217831}
print(result.runtimeType);  //_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
```

when i access the value of `result` as `result['lat']` its give error

`The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'`

my question is how to access the value of `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`

Comment: Cast `result` to a `Map<String, dynamic>` first: `(result as Map<String, dynamic>)['lat']`.  Or better, check its type and allow type promotion to do it for you: `if (result is Map<String, dynamic>) { print(result['lat']); }`.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem and as Sahil says you can cast the result to Map<String, dynamic>. The codes looks like:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(responseData['data']);
// access to your data object
print(data['modules']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var result = jsonDecode(response.body)['result']['geometry']['location'];
Map<String, dynamic> location = Map<String, dynamic>.from(result);
print(location[lat]);
```